# When i opening my domain like www.domain.com it is redirecting to www.www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

When i open my domain with www.domainname.com it is redirecting to www.www.domainname.com

This is my HTTACCESS Code, other than that i didn't insert any redirections. It is developed in PHP & hosted in godaddy

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I try below httacess code, it is redirecting to https://www. (domain name not appending) when i try to open domain like http://www.domainname.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I expect the redirection should be https://www.toours.com for all below cases

- toours.com
- http://toours.com
- https://toours.com
- http://www.toours.com
- https://www.toours.com

Comment: did you clear browser cache before test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable that you are using in your Rule's target becomes `www.example.com` when you go to `http://www.example.com`  and your destination url changes to `www.www.example.com` . 
To fix this you can either replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` with your `non-www domain` or use a different Condition to match against the host header something like the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am getting Corrupted Content Error